# How install Nvelocity im my existent project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nvelocity

I'll need to use NVelocity to show a page with some details peculiar like names, values, dates, etc...

Well, i found the Nvelocity project, and...I don't have idea how install this in my project!

I already downloaded the files src and demo in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12751/Template-merging-with-NVelocity-and-ASP-NET) , but....what I do now?

Help me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install **[nvelocity](http://nuget.org/packages/NVelocity)**  by using [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) Visual Studio extension.

ones you complete NuGet installation, From the Tools menu, select Library Package Manager and then click [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) and run below command

> PM> Install-Package NVelocity

Or you can try [NuGet Packages Using the Dialog](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog)

Comment: Man, Thank you!
Is everything ok...

now...I need to understand how use it kkkkkkk